# Получение изображения организаций

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-places-api

Пользуясь API поиском по организации, можно ли получить изображения заведений? Например баров, кафе. Как они есть на картах яндекса. Может есть способ используя другие API ядекса? В принципе другие API? Имеется Id организации, адрес, название, локация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сегодняшний день нет возможности выгрузить фотографии организации через какой-либо API Яндекса.